# Is it possible to install 2 different versions of an application at the same time

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Won't it have any conflicts? Because I am using an old version of virtual box and I want to try the newest version but I haven't still completed my download in the virtual ose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general software you can often get away with it (depending on what operating system your running and how you configure things).

However, this is VirtualBox. DO NOT RUN TWO VERSIONS AT ONCE. They will almost certainly conflict. Especially if you are using hardware assisted virtualization (VTX).

Answer (score 2):

It completely depends on how the software is written. Some do, some don't.

- If when you install the latest
  version it implements a
  library/file/registry entry in the
  same location as the older version
  and that library/file/registry entry
  is incompatible it will break the
  older version.
- If it doesn't, you should be fine.

Your best bet would be to ask the Virtual Box people themselves.

Comment: Here's an old VirutalBox forum post that says: not likely to ever be done. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=50977